# Is there an R equivalent of other languages triple quotes?

Tags: r, system, cat

I know you can escape special characters with "\"'s, but I'm interesting in creating commands that will go to the terminal that include special characters, and these cannot read the backslashes well.

As a simplified example, I'd like to have a command that looks like:

```
echo hello "w" or'l'd
```

Which could be achieved by something like

```
system(command="""echo hello "w" or'l'd""")
```

But R doesn't handle triple quotes. Is there another way? Even catching the output from cat() would be ok. e.g. newCommand = cat("echo hello \"w\" orld")

Thanks.

Comment: ooh, by adding a single quote to the string you just made it harder and invalidated @flodel's answer (which was correct for the initial version of your question) ...

Comment: it's harder than just using the backslashes (which as pointed out  below aren't actually included internally in the string, only in R's printed representation of it, and hence are probably not as problematic as you think they are), but ``deparse(substitute(`echo hello "w" or 'l' d`))`` works ...

Comment: And for the original, more general, question in the title ? I also need to run (in my case Julia) commands and having a triple quote or something similar would be handy to avoid having to backslash all the `"`s...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can escape the `"` with `\"`. I would also use `shQuote` if your intention is to run system commands. It takes care of the relevant escaping for you...

```
shQuote( "hello \"w\" orld" , type = "cmd" )
#[1] "\"hello \\\"w\\\" orld\""
```

You should be aware that what you see on-screen in the R interpreter is not exactly what the shell will see.. e.g.

```
paste0( "echo " , shQuote( "hello \"w\" orld" , type = "sh") )
#[1] "echo 'hello \"w\" orld'"

system( paste0( "echo " , shQuote( "hello \"w\" orld" , type = "sh") ) )
#hello "w" orld
```

Comment: I think that to use `shQuote` you would have to do : `system(command=paste0("echo ", shQuote("hello \"w\" orld", type="cmd")))`. If I understand correctly, `shQuote` is for strings passed to a command, without a command itself.

Comment: @juba thanks, you're absolutely right. I updated to that effect. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Raw characters [were introduced in R 4.0.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000653.html), released 2020-04-27:

> There is a new syntax for specifying raw character constants similar
> to the one used in C++: r"(...)" with ... any character sequence not
> containing the sequence ‘⁠)"⁠’. This makes it easier to write strings
> that contain backslashes or both single and double quotes. For more
> details see ?Quotes.

```
> cat(r"(echo hello "w" or'l'd)")
echo hello "w" or'l'd
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use single quotes:

```
system(command='echo hello "w" orld')
```

Comment: That would not work on """hello "w" or'l'd""" (note the single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

library(glue)

```
glue('echo hello "w" or{single_quote("l")}d')
```

OR

```
glue('echo hello "w" or{l}d', l = "'l'")
```